# how to resize Text field and Dropdown in DivShot?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, divshot

with Divshot, i added some form fields such as Text filed, or Dropdown menu to my field.
however, i have no idea on how to resize these components: the text box is too short, while the dropdown menu is too long.

an example is the text field like below where i have no idea how to set the size

```
<input class="input-medium" type="text">
```

how can i change the size of this?

thanks a lot

Comment: Can you provide an example by giving us the preview link?

Comment: i added the example above, thanks

Comment: Change the class of fields from 'input-medium' to 'input-large or input-xlarge or input-xxlarge'. Search for 'Relative sizing' [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Divshot, you can change the size of the input in the 'inspector' section. This lets you select the Bootstrap defined inputs.. input-large, input-xlarge, etc..

You could also define a custom CSS class and use it to specify the `width` of your input. Then assign the `custom` (you can name it anything) class to your input..

```
<input class="input-large custom" type="text">
```

Here's an [example on **Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/63311)